# wamp server how to prevent access above root folder by dot dot slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, wamp

How can I prevent access above root? (by dot dot slash)

I can see all files in the partition.

To test access i wrote this script & added a Go UP link:

```
<?php
$PartialPath = @$_GET['p']; if(empty($PartialPath)){ $PartialPath = ''; }else{ $PartialPath = "\\".$PartialPath; }
$PartialPath_Root = dirname(__FILE__);

$ScanPath = $PartialPath_Root . $PartialPath;
echo 'Scan: ',$ScanPath,'<br><br>';

    $Files_arr = scandir($ScanPath);
    foreach ($Files_arr as $file) {
        if ('.' === $file){}
        else if ('..' === $file){  echo '<a href="?p=',$PartialPath,'../" target="_self">.. GO UP </a><br><br>'; }
        else{ echo $file,'<br>'; }
    }
?>
```

unsing @Hamidreza Kalantari answer

I created a filter to detect if path is outside of root:

```
if(Func_AllowOnlyRootPath($PartialPath) == "1"){
    // continue...
}else{
    echo '<br>unsecure path - outside root<br>'; 
    //die('Directory Traversal Prevented');
}

echo '<br>PartialPath: ',$PartialPath, '<br>';
function Func_AllowOnlyRootPath($VerifyPath){ if(empty($VerifyPath)){ return "1"; }  $real_path=realpath($VerifyPath); if(strpos($real_path, ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']))!==0){ return "0"; } return "1"; }
function Func_AllowOnlyPhpScriptPath($VerifyPath){ if(empty($VerifyPath)){ return "1"; }  $real_path=realpath($VerifyPath); if(strpos($real_path, (dirname(__FILE__)))!==0){ return "0"; } return "1"; }
```

Comment: by [chmoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) the directories - make sure php/wamp is running with a different user than admin. _note_: your test doesn't show that a user could type something line `http://root/../../` to get access. It's only your script that has access.

Comment: yes u are right, can I somehow limit the php script access by .htaccess ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `realpath` function to get the actual path(which does not contain any `..`), then check if it begins with root or not:

```
$real_path=realpath($PartialPath);
if(strpos($real_path, $PartialPath_Root)!==0) die('Directory Traversal Prevented');
```

Comment: _"To test access i wrote this script"_ - I don't think the OP just wants to change _the test_, but rather the _access_ he has shown in the test.

Comment: yes, I want to keep my files outside the server root secure

Comment: @user3820120 as Jeff said, you can keep the files that are out of root safe using permissions, but writing such a code will cause directory traversal, and even if you save outer files using permissions, you will expose files that are in root to risk.

Comment: I was expecting, to be something simple, to allow access only to root dir. I tested a text editor from https://github.com/simon-thorpe/editor & i discovered that it can create a New Text Document outside of the root folder. This seems to be a security risk.

Comment: @user3820120 yeah, [link](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal) that's a security risk, but you can limit the user to a specific directory, using a code like my answer.

Comment: Thx, for info :)